# How to override the css using the JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

i am trying to override the inline style of [JQuery dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/)  using `JQuery`, but i am not getting reflection in the program. I want to position the jquery dialog box to some position. I tried overriding the css style, but it didn't work.

now i am trying to override using css.but it is also not working..

How can i do this please suggest.

i want to override this below css using `JQuery`
css code:

```
.ui-dialog{
    display: block;
    height: auto;
    left: 858px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 124px;
    width: 235px;
}
```

JQuery code:

```
$(".ui-dialog").css('position', 'absolute', 'left', '858px');
```

How can i do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$(".ui-dialog").css({'position': 'absolute', 'left': '858px'});
```

Edit: If you want to do this using CSS and are not calculating the left position dynamically, you can give an identifier to the dialog using `dialogClass` and then use the dialog class and put the same css rules in a stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(".ui-dialog").css('position', 'absolute');
$(".ui-dialog").css('left', '858px');
```

Then read up on [jQuery .css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can understand you that you are likely to do set the position and left value and remove all others Then do the followings:

First remove the style:

```
$(".ui-dialog").attr('style',' ');
```

Then attach this style

```
$(".ui-dialog").css({'position':'absolute', 'left': '858px'});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".ui-dialog").css({position:'absolute',left:'858px'});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to call in this way..

$( ".ui-dialog" ).css({
      'position': 'absolute',
      'left': '858px'
    });